# Start Facebook Chat with Another user using Facebook ID

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

Is there any way to start a facebook chat using the messenger application. I know we can lead a user to the messenger application using intents and using their Messenger API. But I want to do is open a chat window directly with particular user using the facebook User Id.
Is that possible?

I found this post
[Android Facebook sdk messaging ID mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389931/android-facebook-sdk-messaging-id-mismatch)
I couldn't really find much else and I was hoping the new messenger API might support that kind of an interaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the first comment of the other thread: That solution does not work with App Scoped IDs, and you don´t get the real IDs anymore. Even if it would be possible, you can only get App Scoped IDs of friends who authorized your App too. Meaning, it´s impossible.

Comment: thanks. I found out on the FB developers group as well. Just that it seems a pretty useful feature to have.

Answer (score 1):

[to start Facebook messenger with a particular user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29651252/3288890)

check this answer dear will help you how to start with particuler user

Answer (score 1):

try this...
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://messaging/" + facebookId));
But you have to know the facebook id .
Ref: [How to open specific contact chat screen in various popular chat/social-networks apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35972329/how-to-open-specific-contact-chat-screen-in-various-popular-chat-social-networks)